# How can i refactor a JavaScript function that contains innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, innerhtml

```js
const box1 = document.getElementById('box1')
const box2 = document.getElementById('box2')
const box3 = document.getElementById('box3')

const box1__input = document.getElementsByClassName('box1__input')
const box2__input = document.getElementsByClassName('box2__input')
const box3__input = document.getElementsByClassName('box3__input')

const box1__flexbasis = document.getElementsByClassName('box1__flexbasis')
const box2__flexbasis = document.getElementsByClassName('box2__flexbasis')
const box3__flexbasis = document.getElementsByClassName('box3__flexbasis')

const box1__flexshrink = document.getElementsByClassName('box1__flexshrink')
const box2__flexshrink = document.getElementsByClassName('box2__flexshrink')
const box3__flexshrink = document.getElementsByClassName('box3__flexshrink')

const box1__upArrow = document.getElementById('box1__upArrow')

const container = document.getElementById('container')
const form__form1 = document.getElementById('form1')

 box1.style.flexGrow = "1"

flexGrowIncrease =(box) => {
    // console.log(parseInt(box1.style.flexGrow) + 1)
    box.style.flexGrow = (parseInt(box.style.flexGrow) +1).toString()
    reportwidth()
   
}

flexGrowDecrease =(box) => {
    // console.log(parseInt(box1.style.flexGrow) + 1)
    box.style.flexGrow = (parseInt(box.style.flexGrow) -1).toString()
    reportwidth()
   
}



getInputValue = ()=> {
    box1.style.flexGrow= box1__input[0].value
    box1.style.flexShrink= box1__flexshrink[0].value
    box1.style.flexBasis = box1__flexbasis[0].value +'px'

    box2.style.flexGrow= box2__input[0].value
    box2.style.flexShrink= box2__flexshrink[0].value
    box2.style.flexBasis = box2__flexbasis[0].value +'px'

    box3.style.flexGrow= box3__input[0].value
    box3.style.flexShrink= box3__flexshrink[0].value
    box3.style.flexBasis= box3__flexbasis[0].value +'px'

    reportwidth()
}

form__form1.addEventListener('change', ()=>getInputValue())

// changeDisplay =()=> {
//     container.style.flexDirection = 'column'
// }

reloadPage = () => window.location.reload();

function reportwidth() {

    box1.innerHTML = `<div>
    <div style="font-size:30px;"><strong>BOX 1</div></strong><br>
    width : ${box1.clientWidth} px <br><br>
    flex-grow : ${box1.style.flexGrow || 1 }<br>
    flex-shrink : ${box1__flexshrink[0].value || 1 }<br>
    flex-basis : ${box1__flexbasis[0].value || 0}px<br><br>
    <b>shorthand</b><br>
    flex : ${box1.style.flexGrow || 1 } ${box1__flexshrink[0].value || 1 } ${box1__flexbasis[0].value || 0}px
    </div>` ;

    box2.innerHTML = `<div>
    <div style="font-size:30px;"><strong>BOX 2</div></strong><br>
    width : ${box2.clientWidth} px <br><br>
    flex-grow : ${box2__input[0].value || 1 }<br>
    flex-shrink : ${box2__flexshrink[0].value || 1 }<br>
    flex-basis : ${box2__flexbasis[0].value || 0} px<br><br>
    <b>shorthand</b><br>
    flex : ${box2__input[0].value || 1 } ${box2__flexshrink[0].value || 1 } ${box2__flexbasis[0].value || 0}px
    </div>` ;

    box3.innerHTML = `<div>
    <div style="font-size:30px;"><strong>BOX 3</div></strong><br>
    width : ${box3.clientWidth} px <br><br>
    flex-grow : ${box3__input[0].value || 1 }<br>
    flex-shrink : ${box3__flexshrink[0].value || 1 }<br>
    flex-basis : ${box3__flexbasis[0].value || 0} px<br><br>
    <b>shorthand</b><br>
    flex : ${box3__input[0].value || 1 } ${box3__flexshrink[0].value || 1 } ${box3__flexbasis[0].value || 0}px
    </div>` ;
    
  }


window.onresize = reportwidth;
window.onload = ()=> {
    reportwidth();
}


var element = document.getElementById('container');


var resizer = document.createElement('div');
resizer.style.width = '15px';
resizer.style.height = '15px';
resizer.style.background = '#e7512b';
resizer.style.position = 'absolute';
resizer.style.right = 0;
resizer.style.bottom = 0;
resizer.style.cursor = 'se-resize';

//Append Child to Element
resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', initResize, false);
element.appendChild(resizer);

//Window funtion mousemove & mouseup
function initResize(e) {
   window.addEventListener('mousemove', Resize, false);
   window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize, false);
}
//resize the element
function Resize(e) {
   element.style.width = (e.clientX - element.offsetLeft) + 'px';
   element.style.height = (e.clientY - element.offsetTop) + 'px';
   reportwidth()
}
//on mouseup remove windows functions mousemove & mouseup
function stopResize(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', Resize, false);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopResize, false);
}
```

```css
body{
    --font-ubuntu : 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    background-color: #fefae0;
}

.main {
    font-family: var(--font-ubuntu);
    margin : 0 auto;
    /* display : flex;
    direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center; */
}
.container {
    margin : 3% auto;
    width : 80vw;
    height: 40vh;
    background-color: #023047;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding : 3%;
    position : relative;
}

.resizer {
    width : 20x;
    height: 20px;
    color: #fefae0;
    position : absolute;
    /* font-weight : bold; */
    right : 0 px;
    top : 80px;

}

.flexInputs{
    margin: 1% auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#form1 {
    /* margin : 0 auto; */
    width : 590px;
    padding : 2%;
    border : 1px solid black;
    /* position : absolute; */
}

/* .Definition__flexgrow{
    margin-top: 3%;
    width : 590px;
    padding : 3%;
    border : 1px solid black;
} */



#box1, #box2, #box3 {
    margin : 0 1%;
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    color: white;
    margin :1%;
    display : flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    font-size : 14px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    background: linear-gradient(140deg, #e7512b, #f4a261);
    width : 50px;
    flex : 1;
 
}


input {
    width : 40px;
    margin-right:20px;
}


button {
    background-color: #023047;
    color : white;
    border : none;
    margin-top : 1%;
    padding:1%;
}

button:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(140deg, #e7512b, #f4a261);
    border : 1px solid #023047
}
h2 {
    /* font-size : 1.5rem; */
    display : inline;
    margin-right: 1%;

}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;

}  .buttonArrow {
    padding : 1%;
    border-radius : 30px;
}

.buttonArrow:hover {
    border : none;
}

.disable-select {
    user-select: none; /* supported by Chrome and Opera */
   -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
   -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
   -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
   -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src='./index.js' defer></script>
    <script src='./drag_elements.js' defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main class="main" id="main">
        <div class="container disable-select" id="container">
            <div id="box1" > </div> 
            <div id="box2"></div>
            <div id="box3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="flexInputs">

            <form id="form1" >
                <h2>BOX 1</h2>
                    <label for="flexWidth">flexGrow :</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="flexWidth" class="box1__input" value="1"  >
                    <!-- <button id="box1__upArrow" onClick="flexGrowIncrease(box1); return false;" class="buttonArrow">+</button>
                    <button id="box1__downArrow" onClick="flexGrowDecrease(box1); return false;" class="buttonArrow">-</button> -->
                    <label for="flexShrink">flexShrink :</label>

                    <input type="number" min="0" name="flexShrink" class="box1__flexshrink" value="1" >
                    <label for="flexbasis">flex-basis :</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="flexbasis" class="box1__flexbasis" value="0">
                <br>
                <h2>BOX 2</h2>
                    <label for="flexWidth">flexGrow :</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="flexWidth" class="box2__input" value="1" >
                    <label for="flexShrink">flexShrink :</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="flexShrink" class="box2__flexshrink" value="1" >
                    <label for="flexbasis">flex-basis :</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="flexbasis" class="box2__flexbasis" value="0">
                <br>
                <h2>BOX 3</h2>
                    <label for="flexWidth">flexGrow :</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="flexWidth" class="box3__input" value="1" >
                    <label for="flexShrink">flexShrink :</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="flexShrink" class="box3__flexshrink" value="1">
                    <label for="flexbasis">flex-basis :</label>
                    <input type="number" min="0" name="flexbasis" class="box3__flexbasis" value="0">
            </form>
            
            <!-- <div class="Definition__flexgrow">  <h1>La propriété flex-grow</h1>
                La propriété flex-grow permet de répartir l'espace disponible en « parts ».
                 Si, pour le premier élément, on indique flex-grow avec une valeur de 2 et, 
                 pour les autres éléments, flex-grow avec une valeur de 1, deux « parts » de l'espace 
                 disponible seront données au premier élément  .</div>

                 <div class="Definition__flexgrow">  <h1>La propriété flex-shrink</h1>
                    La propriété flex-grow permet de gérer la façon dont l'espace est ajouté sur 
                    l'axe principal. La propriété flex-shrink permet quant à elle de contrôler 
                    la façon dont l'espace est réduit.</div> -->
            <!-- <button onclick="getInputValue();">OK</button> -->
            <!-- <button onclick="changeDisplay();">SWITH ROW / COLUMN</button> -->
            <button onclick="reloadPage();">RESET</button>

            
        </div>
    </main>

    
</body>
</html>
```

A have a JavaScript function, which handles a text inside three different boxes. The boxes are quite similar and the way the text is inserted into the box is the same. For now the function is like so:

```
function reportwidth() {

    box1.innerHTML = `<div>
    <div style="font-size:30px;"><strong>BOX 1</div></strong><br>
    width : ${box1.clientWidth} px <br><br>
    flex-grow : ${box1.style.flexGrow || 1 }<br>
    flex-shrink : ${box1__flexshrink[0].value || 1 }<br>
    flex-basis : ${box1__flexbasis[0].value || 0}px<br><br>
    <b>shorthand</b><br>
    flex : ${box1.style.flexGrow || 1 } ${box1__flexshrink[0].value || 1 } ${box1__flexbasis[0].value || 0}px
    </div>` ;

    box2.innerHTML = `<div>
    <div style="font-size:30px;"><strong>BOX 2</div></strong><br>
    width : ${box2.clientWidth} px <br><br>
    flex-grow : ${box2__input[0].value || 1 }<br>
    flex-shrink : ${box2__flexshrink[0].value || 1 }<br>
    flex-basis : ${box2__flexbasis[0].value || 0} px<br><br>
    <b>shorthand</b><br>
    flex : ${box2__input[0].value || 1 } ${box2__flexshrink[0].value || 1 } ${box2__flexbasis[0].value || 0}px
    </div>` ;

    box3.innerHTML = `<div>
    <div style="font-size:30px;"><strong>BOX 3</div></strong><br>
    width : ${box3.clientWidth} px <br><br>
    flex-grow : ${box3__input[0].value || 1 }<br>
    flex-shrink : ${box3__flexshrink[0].value || 1 }<br>
    flex-basis : ${box3__flexbasis[0].value || 0} px<br><br>
    <b>shorthand</b><br>
    flex : ${box3__input[0].value || 1 } ${box3__flexshrink[0].value || 1 } ${box3__flexbasis[0].value || 0}px
    </div>` ;
    
  }
```

so my bet would be to pass a `box` argument into the function, which would be something like:

```
function reportwidth(box) {}
```

but I cannot make this work , because if I do:

```
flex : ${box.style.flexGrow || 1 }
```

in replacement of

```
flex : ${box1.style.flexGrow || 1 }
```

it just does not work...

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: here is the full thing in the snippet

Comment: You shoudl wrap the boxes in a div with a clas and run over `document.querySelectorAll(".boxDiv")` then you could use relative addressing

Comment: yes that sounds good, i'll try that !!